# Full Spring integration with Quartz to implement real time notification e-mails

Tags: spring, spring-boot, notifications, quartz-scheduler

I'm currently developing an application with spring boot that let users to create an appointment. So basically the appointment has a startDateTime and an endDateTime fields + an e-mail. The creation of an appointment adds a new line in the appointment table of a MySql database.

What I want to do is to notify the user one hour before the startDateTime defined in the database with an e-mail. I looked for a solution but couldn't find one. I found that jobs (spring batch) can do this, but jobs rely on a frequency check (days, weeks, months) what I'm looking for is a real-time notification. Any help or guidance for a solution to realise such task is welcomed.

Greetings

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a scheduling library such as [quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/), providing easy integration with Spring framework.

After an appointment is saved in your database, a "send-email" job will be scheduled for the desirable time (one hour before start date for instance).

A "send-email" job must implement `org.quartz.Job` and more specifically `execute` method where you can use your `Autowired` `SendEmailService` implementation.

Below you can find a (almost) complete example of how such a requirement could be implemented in code.

**Update - Code to schedule the job**

First we define a `SchedulingService` interface.

```
public interface SchedulingService {

    startScheduler() throws SchedulerException;

    void standbyScheduler() throws SchedulerException;

    void shutdownScheduler() throws SchedulerException;

    void scheduleJob(JobDetail jobDetail, Trigger trigger) throws SchedulerException;
}
```

And relevant implementation.

```
@Service
public class SchedulingServiceImpl implements SchedulingService {

    @Autowired
    private Scheduler scheduler;

    @Override
    public void startScheduler() throws SchedulerException {
        if (!scheduler.isStarted()) {
            scheduler.start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void standbyScheduler() throws SchedulerException {
        if (!scheduler.isInStandbyMode()) {
            scheduler.standby();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void shutdownScheduler() throws SchedulerException {
        if (!scheduler.isShutdown()) {
            scheduler.shutdown();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void scheduleJob(JobDetail jobDetail, Trigger trigger) throws SchedulerException {
        scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
    }
}
```

Then in `AppointmentServiceImpl` we have a method `createAppointment()` which calls `scheduleSendEmailJob()`.

```
@Service
public class AppointmentServiceImpl implements AppointmentService {

    @Autowired
    private SchedulingService schedulingService;

    public void createAppointment(Appointment appointment) throws SchedulerException {

        // Save appointment to database
        // ...

        // Schedule send email job if appointment has been successfully saved
        scheduleSendEmailJob(appointment);

        return;
    }

    private void scheduleSendEmailJob(Appointment appointment) throws SchedulerException {

        JobDetail jobDetail = JobBuilder.newJob().ofType(SendEmailJob.class)
            .storeDurably()
            .withIdentity(UuidUtils.generateId(), "APPOINTMENT_NOTIFICATIONS")
            .withDescription("Send email notification for appointment")
            .build();


        jobDetail.getJobDataMap().put("appointmentId", appointment.getId());

        Date scheduleDate = appointment.computeDesiredScheduleDate();
        String cronExpression = convertDateToCronExpression(scheduleDate);

        CronTrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().forJob(jobDetail)
            .withIdentity(UuidUtils.generateId(), "APPOINTMENT_NOTIFICATIONS")
            .withDescription("Trigger description")
            .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(cronExpression))
            .build();

        schedulingService.scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
    }

    private String convertDateToCronExpression(Date date) {

        Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();

        if (date == null) return null;

        calendar.setTime(date);

        int year = calendar.get(java.util.Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = calendar.get(java.util.Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
        int day = calendar.get(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int hour = calendar.get(java.util.Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = calendar.get(java.util.Calendar.MINUTE);

        return String.format("0 %d %d %d %d ? %d", minute, hour, day, month, year);
    }
}
```

Class `SendEmailJob` is an implementation of `Job` interface and responsible for sending emails using relevant services.

**Update - Code to pass parameter from scheduling method to actual job execution**

For passing parameters, jobDataMap is being used. For instance:

```
public class SendEmailJob implements Job {

    @Autowired
    private AppointmentService appointmentService;

    @Autowired
    private SendEmailService sendEmailService;

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext) throws JobExecutionException {

        JobDataMap jobDataMap = jobExecutionContext.getJobDetail().getJobDataMap();

        // Retrieving passed parameters
        Long appointmentId = (Long) jobDataMap.get("appointmentId");

        Appointment appointment = appointmentService.findById(appointmentId);

        // Send email
        sendEmailService.sendEmail(appointment);
    }
}
```

*Note:* Appointment object could also been passed from scheduling method to actual job execution, you can just pass:

```
jobDetail.getJobDataMap().put("appointment", appointment);
```

And get:

```
// Retrieving passed parameters
Appointment appointment = (Appointment) jobDataMap.get("appointment");
```

**Update - Configuration code**

Bean `scheduler` is defined in a `@Configuration` class responsible for Quartz initialization.

`SchedulingConfiguration` class is defined as:

```
@Configuration
public class SchedulingConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Bean
    public Scheduler scheduler() throws SchedulerException, IOException {

        StdSchedulerFactory factory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        factory.initialize(new ClassPathResource("properties/quartz.properties").getInputStream());

        Scheduler scheduler = factory.getScheduler();
        scheduler.setJobFactory(springBeanJobFactory());

        return scheduler;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringBeanJobFactory springBeanJobFactory() {
        AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory jobFactory = new AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory();
        jobFactory.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        return jobFactory;
    }

}
```

Our `quartz.properties` file lives in `resources/properties` folder. Note that job persistence database is an Oracle instance.

```
# Configure Main Scheduler Properties
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = AppScheduler
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId = AUTO

# Configure ThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 10
org.quartz.threadPool.threadsInheritContextClassLoaderOfInitializingThread = true

# Configure JobStore
org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold = 60000
org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = 
org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.oracle.OracleDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = APP.QRTZ_
org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties = false
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = appDs
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered = true
org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval = 20000

# Configure Datasources
org.quartz.dataSource.appDs.driver = oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
org.quartz.dataSource.appDs.URL = jdbc:oracle:thin:@dbsrv:1521:appdb
org.quartz.dataSource.appDs.user = db_user
org.quartz.dataSource.appDs.password = db_pwd
org.quartz.dataSource.appDs.maxConnections = 5
org.quartz.dataSource.appDs.validationQuery = select 0 from dual
```

The final step is to call scheduler methods in application context initialization as following (please note added methods in `SchedulingService`):

```
public class SchedulingContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(SchedulingContextListener.class);

    private SchedulingService schedulingService(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        WebApplicationContext springContext = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(sce.getServletContext());
        return springContext.getBean(SchedulingService.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        try {
            this.schedulingService(sce).startScheduler();
        } catch (SchedulerException e) {
            logger.error("Error while Scheduler is being started", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        try {
            this.schedulingService(sce).shutdownScheduler();
        } catch (SchedulerException e) {
            logger.error("Error while Scheduler is being shutdown", e);
        }
    }
}
```

*Note:* `SchedulingContextListener` should be registered in `servletContext` in application initialization, depending on how Spring configuration is defined, either using Spring Boot or traditional Spring MVC Configuration.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Is there a source code example to see how can I schedule the job after the save method is executed on the appointment? It'll be very helpfull

Comment: Updated my answer with suggested sample implementation code. Take a look. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It's more clearer now but I still have one question: when creating the jobdetail using JobBuilder you define only the class job for the type but how this class will know which appointment we're creating the job for and thus retrieve the e-mail of the right person to send the e-mail to? Also it'll be nice if you can post the conf too since in Google they talk a lot about a configuration based on properties files which is very confusing. Thanks again

Comment: @Habchi, I have updated the code with how you can pass parameters from scheduling method to actual job execution. By first chance, I will try to add sample configuration (using a Configuration class and a properties file, but as you will see, it won't be very confusing).

Comment: Hi Thank you for the update. I managed to create a sample, triggers are created in database with the correct CRON, but they're never fired, I tried to change my logging level to trace to have more information, not a single exception to mention. After my appointment is saved, I have this logged in my console:
Lock 'TRIGGER_ACCESS' is desired by: http-nio-8080-exec-1 | Lock 'TRIGGER_ACCESS' is being obtained: http-nio-8080-exec-1 | Lock 'TRIGGER_ACCESS' given to: http-nio-8080-exec-1 and other information that I can't print due to char limits. Triggers are in Waiting state in the database.

Comment: Maybe `SchedulingContextListener` is not being registered in `servletContext` (my bad if this is the case). Can you please insert a breakpoint in method `SchedulingContextListener.contextInitialized()` and check if it executed in application startup? Btw, are you using Spring Boot or (Traditional) Spring MVC configuration?

Comment: I'm using spring boot for my application. Gonna try what you asked me to do and returned to you with a response. Thank you so much

Comment: I can't find SchedulingContextListener  class

Comment: Haven't you implemented above suggested code? `SchedulingContextListener` is the last class described.

Comment: I added the last class described in your response, but still doesn't worked. So I debugged the application and I found out that the listenner is not registred so I added this code to the SchedulingConfiguration class: 

@Bean
    public SchedulingContextListener schedulingContextListener(){
        return new SchedulingContextListener();
    }

And it does work now. Thank you sir, and if you have any suggestions on how to register the listener in an other way, I'm all for it. Thank you again.

Comment: That's what I was going to suggest, you found it anyway. How you choose to register `SchedulingContextListener` depends on whether you are running in Spring boot or no (maybe I will add this as comment in the answer). I'm pretty happy I could help you. I think that a pretty complete reference was made above after all this effort. Maybe we should change title of question, to be more specific about the content. Happy scheduling!

Comment: Yes indeed, I think that this exchange should take a more generic title since it's a complete reference on how to integrate quartz with Spring. Thank you again for your help