# pass JobDataMap in the JobDetailFactoryBean not working

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I'm using `Quartz 2.2.1`. My code is like follows.

```
<bean name="myJob"  class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobClass" value="com.my.MyJob" />
    <property name="durability" value="true" />
    <property name="jobDataAsMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="param" value="myParam" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="myTrigger"  class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="myJob" />
    <property name="cronExpression" value="0 0/1 * * * ?" />
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobDetails">
        <list>
            <ref bean="myJob" />
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="myTrigger" />
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="quartzProperties" ref="quartzProperties"/>
</bean>
```

java class

```
@PersistJobDataAfterExecution
@DisallowConcurrentExecution
public class MyJob extends QuartzJobBean {
    private String param;

    private final org.slf4j.Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Override
    protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext jobContext) throws JobExecutionException {
        JobDataMap jobDataMap = jobContext.getJobDetail().getJobDataMap();
        log.debug("size of jobdatamap {}", jobDataMap.keySet().size());
        log.debug("quartz param {}", param);

        // some code
    }

    public void setParam(String param) {
        this.param = param;
    }

    public String getParam() {
        return param;
    }
}
```

but I always get `param null` and `jobdatamap 0`. I checked several examples in web and those are same like mine.

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId = AUTO
org.quartz.scheduler.makeSchedulerThreadDaemon = true

org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 1
org.quartz.threadPool.makeThreadsDaemons = true

org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
   org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.MSSQLDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = myDB
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = QRTZ_
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered = false

org.quartz.dataSource.myDB.jndiURL = /jdbc/myDB
```

what is I am missing?

Comment: If you want, you can take a look in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46417393/full-spring-integration-with-quartz-to-implement-real-time-notification-e-mails/) where I describe how we define and manage our Quartz Jobs with Spring. Maybe you can find something useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have use the `SchedulerFactoryBean` to pass `JobDataMap` and it is working for me.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobDetails">
        <list>
            <ref bean="myJob" />
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="myTrigger" />
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="quartzProperties" ref="quartzProperties"/>
    <property name="schedulerContextAsMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="param" value="myParam" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```